# Weak solution in Hilbert Space

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How would you show that $u(x)=log|x|$ is a weak solution of $-\Delta u+cu=0$ for some $c(x)\in L_{weak}^{3/2}(B)$ and u is not bounded?
I did take the derivative of u(x) and then its second derivative. I'm confused on how to proceed with it further.

Comment: Formally the idea is to prove that $\frac{-\Delta u}{u}\in L^{3/2}_w(B)$. Write out this quotient, and if you are still stuck post the computations here so that we may help you further, if we can at least.

Comment: Alright, I have $u'=1/r$ and $u''=-1/(r^2)$
Given $\Delta u+cu=0$, $\Delta u=((n-2)/(r^2))v$ where $c=(n-2)/(r^2)$.
This implies that we need to show $(n-2)/(r^2) \in L_w^{3/2} (B)$. I just need a hint to proceed from here.

Comment: I don't understand: What is $v$? I calculate $\Delta u=(n-2)/|x|^2$, so that $c=(n-2)/(|x|^2\ln |x|)$. Are you sure about your computations?

Comment: Also, are you working in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ or...?

Comment: Sorry to not clear this out. I have taken $u(x)=v(|x|)$ and hence $v(r)=log r$. This implies, $v'=1/r$, $v''=-1/(r^2)$. 
Hence, $\Delta u=((n−2)/(r^2))v$ where $c=(n-2)/(r^2)$.
Hope this is more clear.

Comment: I don't see where the $v$ in the expression for $\Delta u$ comes from.

Comment: $\Delta u=v''+((n-1)/r) v'=cv$

Comment: So then shouldn't $c$ be $(n-2)/(r^2v)$?

Comment: Well, $|x|=r$ and as we substitute the value of first and second derivative of v in $\Delta u$, wouldn't v be taken common and the rest be considered c?

Comment: Without taking into account the problem, in general the laplacian of the logarithm shouldn't contain any logarithm terms, it goes away when you take the first derivative. If it's appearing again it means that you must have divided by it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Okay here's what I've got: 
$$
\nabla u = \frac{x}{|x|^2}, \qquad \Delta u = \text{div} \nabla u = \frac{n-2}{|x|^2}.
$$ 
This implies that $c=\frac{n-2}{|x|^2\ln|x|}$. Now I'm confused: Assuming you're working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (is this right?) we decompose $c=c_1+c_2= c1_{B_{1/2}}+c1_{B\setminus B_{1/2}}$. It's easy to see that $|c_1| \leq M |x|^2$ so that clearly $c_1\in L^{3/2}_w(B)$ and no better (i.e. $c_1\notin L^{3/2}(B)$). On the other hand $|c_2| \approx |\ln |x||^{-1}1_{B\setminus B_{1/2}}$ and this is, as far as I can tell (maybe I'm wrong), not in $L^p_w(B)$ for any $p\geq 1$.

In other words, I can conclude your result in $B_\rho$ for any $0<\rho<1$ but not for $B$.